# ASUS UX330UA Fn key for Brightness

Tags: shortcut-keys, asus

I have a ASUS ux330ua and the problem is that the fn shortcut for the volume works but the other shortcuts don't. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

**Screen Brightness Keys**

I have the same problem on a UX305FA, and here's what I did to address it. Rather than pulling my hair out over the issue,

- I installed xbacklight, a command line program for changing screen brightness

  ```
  sudo apt install xbacklight
  ```
- Then I [set custom keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html#custom) that run xbacklight to increase/decrease the brightness. I couldn't get <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> to work as a binding, so I use <kbd>[image: win.png]</kbd>
  +<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> instead.

I don't remember the exact commands I used with xbacklight, but the man page should have enough to get you going.

As for the other keys, I didn't attempt to get any of them working, but you might be able to work out something similar with those as well.